# Set cookie directly for youtube

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I know it's not possible for setting cookies for another domain. But if both domain are owned then we could you a file in the second domain to catch the cookie from the first domain. Otherwise, it's impossible.

My question is, is it anyway that I can write a code (I'm not sure which language is possible) that in a webpage, I could set the cookie for youtube? Or is it anyway that I can set cookie for youtube without going directly to youtube.com?

I would love to hear your ideas. Thank you.

Comment: if there is an answer to this..the hackers of the world would thank you...

Comment: Do you need in `your_website.com` to set a cookies with the same name and value as the Youtube cookies (why would you need so?) or do you need to modify a Youtube cookies so that somehow you can retrieve an existing session?

Comment: I need to modify youtube cookie so I can manipulate my existing session